# The simplest concurrency pattern

Tags: c#, concurrency, semaphore, parallel-processing

Please, would you help me in reminding me of one of the simplest parallel programming techniques.

How do I do the following in C#:

#### Initial state:

```
semaphore counter = 0
```

#### Thread 1:

```
// Block until semaphore is signalled
semaphore.Wait(); // wait until semaphore counter is 1
```

#### Thread 2:

```
// Allow thread 1 to run:
semaphore.Signal(); // increments from 0 to 1
```

It's not a mutex because there is no critical section, or rather you can say there is an infinite critical section. So what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re "how"... well, you could use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx), [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) or reset-event ([ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx), [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)), but personally I use `Monitor` for that;

```
object sync = new object();
```

thread 1:

```
lock(sync) { // blocks until it successfully takes (re-entrant) lock on sync
    // here: launch thread 2, to ensure thread 1 has the lock first
    Monitor.Wait(sync); // releases lock(s) and waits for pulse,
                        // then retakes locks(s) when free
} // releases lock (or decrement by 1)
```

thread 2:

```
lock(sync) { // blocks until it successfully takes (re-entrant) lock on sync
    Monitor.Pulse(sync); // moves a waiting thread into the ready-queue
                         // (but the awoken thread still can't continue until
                         // it gets the lock itself - and we still hold it)
} // releases lock (or decrement by 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is a `lock` needed because `Monitor.Pulse` is not atomic?

Comment: @Ilya - the rule is you can only wait or pulse while you hold the lock. Internally? who knows. But trying either while not holding the lock is instant exception.

Comment: @Ilya as for *why* I use `Monitor` - it doesn't involve the OS ;p (the others all come from OS primitives)

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is simply a mutex; a mutex is basically the same as a semaphore with value 1. And there *is* a 'critical section' - it's the code sequence which is executed while either thread holds the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

A semaphore initialized to 1, *can* be seen [read: *used*] as a mutex.
The specific scenario you are describing is a semaphore **used a signaling system between two threads**.
The first thread tries to lock the resourse [acquire the semaphore] but gets blocked [because the semaphore has been initialized to zero], until the second thread signal thread 1 that he can enter the remaining part of the code.
An excellent article on the topic is:

http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/06/09/81268.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Actually this was my first solution, but then I changed it to Marc's answer because it seemed neater.